# Ingnoring any and all url parameters to harden security. How?

Tags: nginx

Anyone who puts an NGINX server online and looks at its `access.log` a week latter will find lots of URL exploits being attempted. Every day, any time.

So what if, I was to reject any and all url parameters. What if every query string was masked with an NGINX `rewrite` which would fail to match anything not defined as a `rewrite` naturally returning a 404 Not Found?

Or a series of rewrites in order placed inside this always present location block?

```
location / {
  rewrite "^/api/v1/users/?$" /api/v1/Users.php last;
  rewrite "^/api/v1/users/(all|active|inactive)?$" /api/v1/Users.php?status=$1 last;
  rewrite "^/api/v1/users/(\d+)/?$" /api/v1/Users.php?userId=$1 last;
}

# URL Match examples...

http://localhost/api/v1/users
http://localhost/api/v1/users/

http://localhost/api/v1/users/all
http://localhost/api/v1/users/active
http://localhost/api/v1/users/inactive

http://localhost/api/v1/users/2001
http://localhost/api/v1/users/2002
http://localhost/api/v1/users/2003
```

Is there a way to direct NGINX to ignore URL parameters? Feel free to let me know if this is a naive question. Perhaps I'm asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather use `return` instead of `rewrite` because ["rewrite directive can return only code 301 or 302"](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/). For this, create a `location` with a regular expression to catch the specific request uri.

And if you just want to drop all of these requests return a [http status 444](https://httpstatus.in/444/).

Example:

```
server {
    # ...
    location ~* ^/api/v1/users/.*$ {
        return  444;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example location that is passing parameters like in my `rewrite` examples? I just never been able to convert it.

Comment: This regular expression should match all your examples, or did I miss something?

Comment: Yeah. You provided an example that blocks. I needed to see an example that serves coexisting with your example. The other rewrites turned into location blocks.

Comment: I think that when you want to assign back references to different parameters in a rediect then "series of rewrites" is the only viable way. I'm still not sure if I understood what exactly you're trying to achieve, sorry.